# Python: Issue subsetting rows of pandas dataframe using .isin()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset, rows

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns named 't' and 'y', which contain floats. Column 't' contains the numbers from 0 to 200 (inclusive) in increments of 0.1. My goal is to subset the rows of the data frame for which t is an *integer* between 0 and 200 (inclusive). My attempt to do this produced strange results. You can find the data I'm using from Github [here](https://github.com/MichaelBarmann/sample-data/blob/master/sample_data.xlsx) to reproduce my results.

Side note: I apologize for linking data, but I strangely could not reproduce the results I was getting by generating two arbitrary sets of values using numpy.arange (adding to my confusion...).

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\Users\Leonidas\Documents\sample_data.xlsx')
data = data.parse(sheet_name = "Sheet1")

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['t','y']
nums = np.arange(0,201)

df2 =  df.loc[df['t'].isin(nums)]

print(df2)
```

This is the output I got:

```
        t         y 
0     0.0  1.000000
20    2.0  0.999710
30    3.0  0.999576
40    4.0  0.999446
190  19.0  0.997854
200  20.0  0.997768
210  21.0  0.997684
220  22.0  0.997602
230  23.0  0.997521
240  24.0  0.997443
250  25.0  0.997367
740  74.0  0.995241
750  75.0  0.995219
```

This code has subsetted the rows where t = 0,2,3,4,19,20,21,...,25,74,75. (???) I was expecting to have the rows where t = 0,1,2,3,...,200. I'm quite baffled by why only a few (seemingly random) selection of the rows I wanted are being subsetted...Any insight/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `isin` will only work for exact occurences. In your file, it seems there is a lot of small decimals like 199.999999999992 (it displays as 200 in Excel) in column t

Comment: Ah, this must be the cause of the problem! Is there a way to introduce a tolerance when comparing sets of values? (i.e. subset all rows where t is within 10e-4 of some number in np.arange(0,201)?

Comment: You may round the column before checking `isin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment the values on column `t` of your dataset are not exact integers. I tested the following code, and it seems that rounding works:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("https://github.com/MichaelBarmann/sample-data/raw/master/sample_data.xlsx", "Sheet1")
nums = np.arange(0,201)
df2 = df.loc[df['t'].round(2).isin(nums)]
print(df2['t'].values)
```

will output

```
[  0.   1.   2.   3.   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.  11.  12.  13.
  14.  15.  16.  17.  18.  19.  20.  21.  22.  23.  24.  25.  26.  27.
  28.  29.  30.  31.  32.  33.  34.  35.  36.  37.  38.  39.  40.  41.
  42.  43.  44.  45.  46.  47.  48.  49.  50.  51.  52.  53.  54.  55.
  56.  57.  58.  59.  60.  61.  62.  63.  64.  65.  66.  67.  68.  69.
  70.  71.  72.  73.  74.  75.  76.  77.  78.  79.  80.  81.  82.  83.
  84.  85.  86.  87.  88.  89.  90.  91.  92.  93.  94.  95.  96.  97.
  98.  99. 100. 101. 102. 103. 104. 105. 106. 107. 108. 109. 110. 111.
 112. 113. 114. 115. 116. 117. 118. 119. 120. 121. 122. 123. 124. 125.
 126. 127. 128. 129. 130. 131. 132. 133. 134. 135. 136. 137. 138. 139.
 140. 141. 142. 143. 144. 145. 146. 147. 148. 149. 150. 151. 152. 153.
 154. 155. 156. 157. 158. 159. 160. 161. 162. 163. 164. 165. 166. 167.
 168. 169. 170. 171. 172. 173. 174. 175. 176. 177. 178. 179. 180. 181.
 182. 183. 184. 185. 186. 187. 188. 189. 190. 191. 192. 193. 194. 195.
 196. 197. 198. 199. 200.]
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If column t is made of 0.1 increments, you can simply select every 10th column

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'t': [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0], 'y': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]})

df1 = df.iloc[::10, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trivial way to do that:

```
# To reduce the list to integers, use: 
df[df.t == df.t.astype(int)]

==>    
        t         S
0     0.0  1.000000
20    2.0  0.999710
30    3.0  0.999576
40    4.0  0.999446
190  19.0  0.997854
200  20.0  0.997768
210  21.0  0.997684
...
```

To further reduce the list to items in a certain range, use:

```
df[(df.t == df.t.astype(int)) & (df.t >= 0) & (df.t <= 200.0)]
```

Please note that *comparison with floats is tricky*. Because of the limitations of floating point, for example, `a + b == c` doesn't imply that `c - b == a`.

Comment: This produces the same output I got, but not the output I wanted. I'd like all the rows where t is an integer between 0 and 200 inclusive.